# log4net with .net standard library called inside windows service

Tags: c#, .net-core, windows-services, log4net

I have a .netstandard 2.0 library which consumes log4net nuget version 2.0.8. I have a windows service(.net framework 4.6.1) that consumes the library.

I referred following links:
[configuring log4net in .net core](https://stackify.com/making-log4net-net-core-work/)

The log4net logging works as expected in .net core app. but when deployed with the windows service gives error.

(FileNotFoundException: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=4.1.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.)

While deploying I am putting following files into the deployment folder (from windows service bin folder):

(1) windows service .exe file and exe.config file

(2) a log4net.config xml file containing the log4net configuration consumed as mentioned in link above

(3) netstandard.dll

(4) PublishOutput folder, after publishing the .netstandard library (there is no Runtime dll in that folder)

(5) install the windows service and start (windows 8.1 OS)

Following are log4net nuget references shown:

[image]

Am I missing something or is it not possible to run the log4net from windows service with the given versions?

Additional Info:
log4net configured as follows:

```
var logRepository = LogManager.GetRepository(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly());
log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure(logRepository, new FileInfo("log4net.config"));
ILog _logger = LogManager.GetLogger(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly(), "someValue");
```

**UPDATE 1:**

I added following dlls to the deployment folder:

- System.Runtime.dll
- System.Reflection.dll
- System.IO.FileSystem.dll
- System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation.dll

This resolved the FileNotFoundException. Now I am getting following exception:

*System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'log4net.Core.LoggerManager' threw an exception. ---> System.MethodAccessException: Attempt by security transparent method 'log4net.Core.LoggerManager.GetVersionInfo()' to access security critical method 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation.get_FrameworkDescription()' failed.
Assembly 'log4net, Version=2.0.8.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=669e0ddf0bb1aa2a' is marked with the AllowPartiallyTrustedCallersAttribute, and uses the level 2 security transparency model.  Level 2 transparency causes all methods in AllowPartiallyTrustedCallers assemblies to become security transparent by default, which may be the cause of this exception.
   at log4net.Core.LoggerManager.GetVersionInfo()
   at log4net.Core.LoggerManager..cctor()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at log4net.Core.LoggerManager.GetRepository(Assembly repositoryAssembly)*

**UPDATE 2:**
Going with following approach seems to resolve some of the issues and at least gets the application started. I added the tag `<CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>true</CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>` to the .net standard library csproj file. Hence, on compiling the library I get all the referred dlls for referenced projects and nuget libraries. I placed these in deployment folder first and then copy pasted the dlls obtained from the building the windows service. Now the applications starts working but gives other issues which I am looking into.

Important: Also had to add the log4net nuget reference to the windows service otherwise the service does not work. Wondering if all the nuget references used in the netstandard libraries need also to be added to the windows service project?

Is there any documentation of how to deploy a windows service referring .netstandard libraries?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can help you:

https://www.hanselman.com/blog/ReferencingNETStandardAssembliesFromBothNETCoreAndNETFramework.aspx

The advice is to remove all nuget-packages from you NET461-csproj, and then add this setting to the csproj-file (within the first `<PropertyGroup>`):

```
<RestoreProjectStyle>PackageReference</RestoreProjectStyle>
```

Then re-add the wanted nuget-packages, and it should support NetCore from Net461-projects.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Are all the nuget packages used in any of the referenced .net standard libraries to be added to the windows service also?!

Comment: When RestoreProjectStyle = PackageReference, then nuget-dependencies will work again when adding NetCore-nuget-packages to net461 project. So just add the nuget-package used directly by the net461-project (any dependent nuget-packages will then automatically join the party)